# Do I need to complete AC3 to understand AC4?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I just bought Assassins Creed Revelations, 3 & 4.
I already played 1, 2 & Brotherhood, so I started to end the Ezio story with finishing Revelations.

I just watched some trailers for AC 4 and i'm excited and just want to start to play it. But I don't know if there are some relations to AC3...? When I google about it, there are too many spoilers because they talk too much about the story. SO PLEASE DO NOT SPOILER! I just want to know if I need to play Assassins Creed 3 first, before I start with the 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - as far as I can tell, the stories are almost entirely unrelated.

Comment: I agree. You might not understand a few goings on between Abstergo and Desmonds crew, but that is about it.

Comment: @Lyrical: Thank you for your feedback. Is this important to understand?

Comment: @DarkDecipio I wouldn't say it is vital. Personally I prefer the individual stories in each AC game. Is there any reason you don't want to play AC3 other than AC4 looking good? AC3 for me was a pretty enjoyable game, it does start off very slow though.

Comment: I only have 1 AC game, AC4, and I havnt needed to know anything from AC3 and I have completed the game.

Comment: @Lyrical: Nah, AC 3 also looks good but I'm too excited about the pirate atmosphere. So I want to AC 4 now :). As you said about the individual stories, AC Brotherhood and Revelations should both be played successively. Because Brotherhood continuous the story of Brotherhood.
After AC4, I would play AC3. If I wouln't it was a bad bought :) 

Okay thank you. `+1` & accepted.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the whole ship sailing / fighting mechanic in AC4 is also in AC3 - you get to do ship to ship battles in that too.

Comment: The ending of AC 3 was shoved into a final cinematic. There was next to no exposition of any real merit then all of a sudden they tried to tie it all up. I, personally (and this is just opinion), got the feeling / impression they ran out of time / money and just finished it out of the blue. You could watch it on Youtube and just play the fourth one. AC 3 was the weakest of them so far. It pushed plausibility too far, and the historical setting was tedious. I'm finding 4 better, but god the tutorials give you false information at times, and the grinding for the ship is, to me, beyond boring!

Comment: In story elements AC3 is seen as the weakest, in gameplay and launch ac unity is seen as the weakest, the overall best series is the Ezio Saga

Answer (score 1):

There are absolutely no references to AC3 in the main (Edward Kenway) section of the game. In the Abstergo Research Assistant position, there are one or two videos about the ending of AC3, but it is not related to the story.

Some characters from the present-day section of past AC games make a small appearance in ACIV, but they directly don't play a major role in the story, and the parts they do play have nothing to do with any previous game.

You **will be** able to fully understand the game's plot without playing AC3

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between AC4 and AC3 where in AC4, you will play as Edward Kenway who is the father of Haytham Kenway and grandfather of Connor Kenway in AC3.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary although if you do not play AC3  you won't understand or be able to appreciate the surprise "didn't see that coming" ending.

Answer (score -1):

thats true there is not a big deal if u have not played ac3  but there is a small connection between ac3 and ac4

ac3 was set in 1775 in the american revelutionary war  and ac4 takes place in the 1716 in ac4's ending   nathan kenway  the chacracter who makes an apperance in ac3 was edward kenways son (i think so) so yeah :)